# Determine if two date ranges overlap using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

We have a situation in our in-house built software where we accept `start_time TIMESTAMP` and `end_time TIMESTAMP NULL` for a policy to be effective. The important catch here is that end date can be null as well which means that a policy can be in effect for unlimited period of time unless ended explicitly. I have seen few solutions on stackoverflow but either they are not SQL Based or given that `end_time NOT NULL`. We want to ensure that when we add a new policy it does not overlap with existing policy.

The example schema for policies table is given below

```
CREATE TABLE public.policies
(
    id uuid,
    start_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    end_time timestamp without time zone,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Example Data Feed

```
INSERT INTO policies (id, start_time, end_time) VALUES
('5c056e24-9633-4bb9-b231-fbcab2d4e943', '2020-09-01 00:00:00', '2020-09-05 23:59:59'),
('4e38fd23-6f41-4022-addd-6e3feaa838e0', '2020-09-06 00:00:00', '2020-09-06 23:59:59'),
('e41fe1e5-e433-40a2-9d07-d046f8ca4bfc', '2020-09-07 00:00:00', NULL);
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for indicating this. I am editing this now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is where [ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) come in handy:

```
select *
from policies
where tsrange(start_time, end_time, '[]') && tsrange(check_start, check_end, '[]');
```

`check_start` and `check_end` would be the parameters you want to check. The ranges in the above example are "closed" ranges, i.e. the *include* both edges. If e.g. the upper bound is exclusive, use `'[)'` instead.

A null value is equal to "no end", so this will handled automatically.

Using a tsrange you can also create an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) that would prevent inserting overlapping ranges.

Comment: This answer looks promising but the only exception I found is it is not passing when check_end is NULL

Comment: I have added the example schema and test data to run against. The test I ran which is not passing is `select * from policies where (start_time, end_time) overlaps ('2020-09-01 00:00:00', null);`

Comment: @AppDevD: if `overlaps()` doesn't handle it correctly, use the tsrange

Comment: Worked Beautify. You're a Hero. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have parameters :start and :end for the new policy.  Then the following logic returns all existing rows that overlap with that timeframe:

```
select p.*
from policies p
where p.start_time < :end and (p.end_time > :start or p.end_time is null);
```

Two time periods overlap is one starts before the second ends and it ends after the second starts.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. What if for any existing policy end_time is null, how do we catch that?

Comment: @AppDevD . . . You did have that in your question, didn't you.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a pattern I've used to take into account possibly null values in a where clause

```sql
select *
from table_name
where start_time < :end and (end_time is null or end_time > :start);
```